# Google Analytics - Page Tracking

Tags: google-analytics

My aim is to create a database that will contain all activities per ClientID+time.

That is each session activity (pageviews and conversions) for each ClientID will eventually be included in one row.  To do that I will download the data from custom reports I will create.

My question is: How can I get pagetracking data for all the pages of my website per session / ClientID?

Answer (score 0):

To get the data you require a good place to start is this blog post by Simo Ahava.

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/

To get the data out in a usable format that you outlined you will most likely need to use a program like R or Python (depending on website traffic). This is because of the 10,000 row limit (loop downloads to overcome this), and Google Analytics sampling (download daily/hourly data to overcome this).

Once you have downloaded the list, you will need to pivot/groupby to get the data you are looking for. You also might need to re-write/exclude some URL's depending on how many unique URL's your site has.